# Functions that can take parameters via the URL or POST

Tags: php, post, functional-programming

I have come across a scenario where sometimes I will need to pass parameters to a function via post e.g. an ajax call for real time data, and the default style of passing a parameter i.e. `myFunc($param)`.

I have started to do this the following way:

```
public function createNote($note = null)
  {
    if($note == null) // If param didn't come in by a call or url...
    {
      $note = $_POST['note']; // Use the post data.
    }
    // Do stuff with $note...
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with what I am doing or is this the best way?

Comment: One thing: you're not checking whether `$_POST['note']` exists (`isset()`). Something else, could you not set `$note = $_POST['note']` before calling the function?

Comment: Personally I would just call `createNote($_POST['note'])` instead of that if, but that is more of a "best practice" question and not quite suitable for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using default arguments, below is a small improvement.

```
public function createNote($note = null)
  {
    if(!empty($note) && validate($note)) //if inside class use $this->validate($note)
    {
         // Do stuff with $note...
    }

  }

public function validate($note){
    //do your validations here
}
```

Call the function using createNote($_POST['note']);

Also passing URL arguments directly to functions is not a good practice. You need to first validate them before using.

Comment: in terms of validation do you mean every parameter that is sent to my functions should have the basic strip tags etc performed on it?

Comment: Yes...Also check for any invalid characters that could break you code....